# nvim jdtls cannot recognize ` org.springframwork.security.*` package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I have setup jdtls and I want to use nvim to develop spring-boot projects however I have faced this problem.

every import works fine, the problem is, when I import `org.springframework.security` I don't now why but `jdtls` cannot recognize that package.

**however when I open the project on intellij** it does not shows me any error.

[image: jdtls nvim import error]

- here is my `java.lua` file:

```
local jdtls_ok = pcall(require, "jdtls")

if not jdtls_ok then
  vim.notify "JDTLS not found, install with `:LspInstall jdtls`"
  return
end

local home = os.getenv('HOME')
local jdtls = require('jdtls')

local JDTLS_LOCATION = "/home/drghost/jdt-language-server"

-- Installation location of jdtls by nvim-lsp-installer
-- local JDTLS_LOCATION = vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/lsp_servers/jdtls"


-- File types that signify a Java project's root directory. This will be
-- used by eclipse to determine what constitutes a workspace
local root_markers = {'gradlew', 'mvnw', '.git'}
local root_dir = vim.fs.dirname(vim.fs.find(root_markers, { upward = true })[1])

-- eclipse.jdt.ls stores project specific data within a folder. If you are working
-- with multiple different projects, each project must use a dedicated data directory.
-- This variable is used to configure eclipse to use the directory name of the
-- current project found using the root_marker as the folder for project specific data.
local project_name = vim.fn.fnamemodify(vim.fn.getcwd(), ":p:h:t")
local workspace_folder = home .. "/.cache/jdtls/workspace/" .. project_name

local extendedClientCapabilities = jdtls.extendedClientCapabilities
extendedClientCapabilities.resolveAdditionalTextEditsSupport = true
-- local workspace_folder = home .. "/.local/share/eclipse/" .. vim.fn.fnamemodify(vim.fn.getcwd(), ":p:h:t")

-- Helper function for creating keymaps
function nnoremap(rhs, lhs, bufopts, desc)
  bufopts.desc = desc
  vim.keymap.set("n", rhs, lhs, bufopts)
end



local config = {
  flags = {
    allow_incremental_sync = true,
    debounce_text_changes = 80,
  },
  init_options = {
      bundle = {},
  },
  root_dir = root_dir, -- Set the root directory to our found root_marker
  -- Here you can configure eclipse.jdt.ls specific settings
  -- These are defined by the eclipse.jdt.ls project and will be passed to eclipse when starting.
  -- See https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/wiki/Running-the-JAVA-LS-server-from-the-command-line#initialize-request
  -- for a list of options
  settings = {
    java = {
      eclipse = {
          downloadSources = true,
      },
      gradle = {
          enabled = true,
      },
      maven = {
          downloadSources = true,
      },
      implementationsCodeLens = {
          enabled = true,
      },
      referencesCodeLens = {
          enabled = true,
      },
      references = {
          includeDecompiledSources = true,
      },
      format = {
          enable = true,
        settings = {
          -- Use Google Java style guidelines for formatting
          -- To use, make sure to download the file from https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml
          -- and place it in the ~/.local/share/eclipse directory
          url = "/.local/share/eclipse/eclipse-java-google-style.xml",
          profile = "GoogleStyle",
        },
      },
      signatureHelp = { enabled = true },
      contentProvider = { preferred = 'fernflower' },  -- Use fernflower to decompile library code
      -- Specify any completion options
      completion = {
        favoriteStaticMembers = {
          "org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat",
          "org.hamcrest.Matchers.*",
          "org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*",
          "org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*",
          "java.util.Objects.requireNonNull",
          "java.util.Objects.requireNonNullElse",
          "org.mockito.Mockito.*",
          "org.springframework.*"
        },
       importOrder = {
        "java",
        "javax",
        "com",
        "org"
      },
      },
      -- Specify any options for organizing imports
      sources = {
        organizeImports = {
          starThreshold = 9999;
          staticStarThreshold = 9999;
        },
      },
      -- How code generation should act
      codeGeneration = {
        toString = {
          template = "${object.className}{${member.name()}=${member.value}, ${otherMembers}}"
        },
        hashCodeEquals = {
          useJava7Objects = true,
        },
        useBlocks = true,
      },
      -- If you are developing in projects with different Java versions, you need
      -- to tell eclipse.jdt.ls to use the location of the JDK for your Java version
      -- See https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/wiki/Running-the-JAVA-LS-server-from-the-command-line#initialize-request
      -- And search for `interface RuntimeOption`
      -- The `name` is NOT arbitrary, but must match one of the elements from `enum ExecutionEnvironment` in the link above
      configuration = {
        runtimes = {
          {
            name = "JavaSE-19",
            path = "/usr/bin/java",
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
  -- cmd is the command that starts the language server. Whatever is placed
  -- here is what is passed to the command line to execute jdtls.
  -- Note that eclipse.jdt.ls must be started with a Java version of 17 or higher
  -- See: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls#running-from-the-command-line
  -- for the full list of options
  cmd = {
    'java',
    '-Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1',
    '-Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4',
    '-Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product',
    '-Dlog.protocol=true',
    '-Dlog.level=ALL',
    '-Xmx4g',
    '--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM',
    '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED',
    '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED',
    -- If you use lombok, download the lombok jar and place it in ~/.local/share/eclipse
    -- '-javaagent:' .. home .. '/.local/share/eclipse/lombok.jar',

    -- The jar file is located where jdtls was installed. This will need to be updated
    -- to the location where you installed jdtls
    '-jar', vim.fn.glob(JDTLS_LOCATION .. '/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar'),

    -- The configuration for jdtls is also placed where jdtls was installed. This will
    -- need to be updated depending on your environment
    '-configuration', JDTLS_LOCATION .. "/config_" .. "linux",

    -- Use the workspace_folder defined above to store data for this project
    '-data', workspace_folder,
  },


}
-- Finally, start jdtls. This will run the language server using the configuration we specified,
-- setup the keymappings, and attach the LSP client to the current buffer
jdtls.start_or_attach(config)

local opts= { nnoremap= true, silent=true }
```

I have tried messing up with the configuration but nothing changed

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.